# dplyr::tbl() returning 0 rows from BigQuery external tables

Tags: r, google-bigquery, dbplyr, r-dbi, bigrquery

I'm using `bigrquery` and `dplyr`/`dbplyr` to connect and interact with tables on Google BigQuery. I've noticed that calling `dplyr::tbl()` or `DBI::dbReadTable()` on a managed table correctly returns a preview of the first 10 rows, but running the same on an external table returns a 0 row preview (albeit with the correct schema).

Is there a way to get external tables to work with `dplyr::tbl()` the way that managed tables do? Or is this a limitation of BQ external tables noting that you ["cannot run a BigQuery job that exports data from an external table"](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/external-tables#limitations)?

```r
# These return 0 rows
dplyr::tbl(bq_con, 'mtcars_ext')
#> Job complete
#> Billed: 0 B
#> # Source:   table<mtcars_ext> [0 x 11]
#> # Database: BigQueryConnection
#> # ℹ 11 variables: mpg <dbl>, cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, wt <dbl>, qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>, gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>

DBI::dbReadTable(bq_con, 'mtcars_ext')
#> # A tibble: 0 × 11
#> # ℹ 11 variables: mpg <dbl>, cyl <dbl>, disp <dbl>, hp <dbl>, drat <dbl>, wt <dbl>, qsec <dbl>, vs <dbl>, am <dbl>, gear <dbl>, carb <dbl>

# Verifying that this table has data in it
DBI::dbGetQuery(bq_con, str_glue('SELECT * FROM {project_id}.ds_edw.mtcars_ext'))
#> Job complete
#> Billed: 0 B
#> Downloading first chunk of data.
#> First chunk includes all requested rows.
#> # A tibble: 32 × 11
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  2  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#>  [...]
```

I've tested this with the same results across multiple accounts, as well as `bigrquery` 1.4.2, 1.4.2.9; `dbplyr` 2.2.1, 2.3.0, 2.4.0; `DBI` 1.1.3.

It appears that the external table does return rows once `compute()` is run over it (at least in `dbplyr` 2.2.1). I need to be able to chain `dplyr` verbs on the `tbl()` object so I've opted to use a no-op function to force the table to compute. I suspect that both of these methods create a BQ temporary table which is the workaround that Google recommends for external tables in their documentation (linked above). However, this means that running the modified `tbl()` call has an additional cost attached to it, whereas the same call on managed tables is not billed.

```r
# This works in dbplyr 2.2.1 but not 2.4.0
tbl(bq_con, str_glue('{project_id}.ds_edw.mtcars_ext')) %>% 
  mutate(dummy_col = 1) %>% 
  select(-dummy_col)
#> Job complete
#> Billed: 0 B
#> Job complete
#> Billed: 10.49 MB
#> Downloading first chunk of data.
#> First chunk includes all requested rows.
#> # Source:   SQL [?? x 11]
#> # Database: BigQueryConnection
#>     mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#> 1  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#> 2  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#> [...]

# Compared to 0 cost with managed table
# NB: this result has not been cached in BQ prior

tbl(bq_con, 'mtcars_mgd')
#> Job complete
#> Billed: 0 B
#> # Source:   table<mtcars_mgd> [?? x 11]
#> # Database: BigQueryConnection
#>      mpg   cyl  disp    hp  drat    wt  qsec    vs    am  gear  carb
#>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#>  1  24.4     4  147.    62  3.69  3.19  20       1     0     4     2
#>  2  22.8     4  141.    95  3.92  3.15  22.9     1     0     4     2
#>  [...]
```

Comment: Given that you get the same behavior when you use a `dplyr ::tbl` and `DBI::dbReadTable` this appears to be a property of the connection or the database, not a property of dplyr.